# how to save a document with file extension xlst

Tags: excel

Hi Have a study question and have no idea

Create a template you can use to record each month’s rainfall. Save it as Activity11.xlst. Include a formula or function that totals the month’s rainfall.

A spreadsheet template that allows the month, year and rainfall for each day of the month to be recorded.

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I have basic knowledge only in XML.it is a post regarding saving xls type stylesheet. I think similar concept would be applicable for xlst as well . created an xsl sheet. save it?. All you have to do is name the XSL file with the .xsl extension and reference it in the XML document with the below processing instruction:
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="filename.xsl" ?>

Be sure to put this at the top of the page before any tags. Best place is after the XML declaration but before your first tag

[devshed forum](http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/save-file-xsl-26363.html)